# Webalizer IgnoreURL and IgnoreHost not working

Tags: webalizer

I installed `MOD_DAV_SVN` for my apache and subversion. When I read the report of `Webalizer`, there's a lot of annoying record about svn. I have read the [online manual of webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/webalizer.1.html), and add the following configs in `/etc/webalizer.conf`:

```
IgnoreSite      192.168.1.*
IgnoreURL       /svn*
IgnoreAgent     SVN
```

After modification, I rebuild the record using `webalizer -i` command to ignore all history data. The `IgnoreAgent` is worked, however, those records which contains `/svn` path still show up in the webalizer report like the following picture. [image]

The `IgnoreSite` is not working neither. Any suggession, please?

Comment: have you had an resolution to this? do you even remember this question exists? My application of this issue is slightly different - I'm trying to IgnoreSite for an IP address (with dashes in place of periods).